# Calculate limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty}4\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n-1}-5\sqrt{n+7}+2\sqrt{n-3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Calculate the limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty}4\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n-1}-5\sqrt{n+7}+2\sqrt{n-3}$

I've tried some algebraic tricks but it didn't lead me to the limit..
Hope you'll help, thanks :)

Comment: Did you mean $n\to 0$?

Comment: The question is to calculate the limit of:
$An = 4\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n-1}-5\sqrt{n+7}+2\sqrt{n-3}$

Comment: So the limit as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: yes, limit as n→∞

Comment: Then why isn't that in your question?

Comment: Because someone have changed it and I didn't notice

Comment: Your original question had $x\to 0$.

Comment: You have a mistake, it was n to infinity.

Comment: Cryptic answer: since $2-1+4-5=0$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x}\to 0$ as $x\to +\infty$, the outcome is zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that

$$4\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n-1}-5\sqrt{n+7}+2\sqrt{n-3}=$$
$$4(\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n})-(\sqrt{n-1}-\sqrt{n})-5(\sqrt{n+7}-\sqrt{n})+2(\sqrt{n-3}-\sqrt{n})$$

So you just need to find the limit of 
$$\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt{n}$$

Comment: Why the equality exists after subtraction $-\sqrt{n}$ from every square root?

Comment: @OranSherf, there are two additions and two subtractions, so the $-\sqrt n$'s cancel out.

Answer (score 2):

$$4\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n-1}-5\sqrt{n+7}+2\sqrt{n-3}\\
=(\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n-1})+3(\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n+7})+2(\sqrt{n-3}-\sqrt{n+7})\\
={3-(-1)\over\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n-1}}+{3(3-7)\over\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n+7}}+{2(-3-7)\over\sqrt{n-3}+\sqrt{n+7}}\\
\to0\qquad\text{as }n\to\infty$$

Comment: Ah, I see Rene Schipperus has posted essentially the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider any function $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\sqrt{x+b_k}$$ and define $$A=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$$ Then:

- **If $A\ne0$:** Then, for every $b$, $\sqrt{x+b}\sim\sqrt x$ when $x\to\infty$ hence $f(x)\sim A\sqrt x$, in particular, $$f(x)\to\mathrm{sign}(A)\cdot\infty$$
- **If $A=0$:** Then, using the identities $$\sqrt{x+b}-\sqrt x=\frac b{\sqrt{b+x}+\sqrt x}$$ for every $b$, and the fact that $A=0$, one gets $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^na_k(\sqrt{x+b_k}-\sqrt x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_kb_k}{\sqrt{x+b_k}+\sqrt x}=O\left(\frac1{\sqrt x}\right)$$ in particular, $$f(x)\to0$$

> *Only fact (really) needed:* For every $b$, when $x\to\infty$, $\sqrt{x+b}-\sqrt x\to0$.

Answer (score 0):

If the following limit exists
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{4\sqrt{1+3x^2}-\sqrt{1-x^2}-5\sqrt{1+7x^2}+2\sqrt{1-3x^2}}{x}
$$
then it is equal to your limit (via $n=1/x^2$).

This is just a derivative:
$$
4\frac{6x}{2\sqrt{1+3x^2}}-\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}
-5\frac{14x}{2\sqrt{1+7x^2}}+2\frac{-6x}{2\sqrt{1-3x^2}}
$$
Evaluate at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1 + x} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}x + o(x)$ as $x \to 0$. Proceed as follows:
\begin{align}
& 4\sqrt{n + 3} - \sqrt{n - 1} - 5\sqrt{n + 7} + 2\sqrt{n - 3} \\
= & \sqrt{n}\left(4\sqrt{1 + \frac{3}{n}} - \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{n}} - 5\sqrt{1 + \frac{7}{n}} + 2\sqrt{1 - \frac{3}{n}}\right) \\
= & \sqrt{n}\left[4\left(1 + \frac{3}{2n} + o(1/n)\right) - \left(1 - \frac{1}{2n} + o(1/n)\right) \right. \\
 & \left.- 5\left(1 + \frac{7}{2n} + o(1/n)\right) + 2\left(1 - \frac{3}{2n} + o(1/n)\right)\right] \\
= & \sqrt{n}\left(\frac{-28}{2n} + o(1/n) \right) \\
= & -\frac{14}{\sqrt{n}} + o(1/\sqrt{n}) \to 0 \text { as } n \to \infty.
\end{align}